# Ошибка: The method ... of type ... must override a superclass method

Tags: openjdk, java

Здравствуйте.

Ошибка при компиляции с OpenJDK. 
Ситуация следующая. Есть нижеприведённый код:

```
class MyAction extends AbstractAction {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        // что-то делаем...

    }

}
```

Вроде всё нормально, и Eclipse ошибку не показывает. Но при попытке компиляции из консоли выскакивает ошибка

> "The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type MyClass.MyAction must override a superclass method".

Такая ошибка обычно появляется в тех случаях, когда не совпадает сигнатура или тип возвращаемого переопределяемой функцией значения, или, что то же самое, при помещении Override над методом, который не имеет "прототипов" в классе-родителе. Во-вторых, IDE такие ошибки отлавливает, подчёркивает и ничего не хочет компилировать. А здесь всё выглядит нормально. Что характерно, с обычным JDK эта ошибка не появляется. Структура пакетов там, насколько я помню, та же самая, что и в стандартном JDK - `java.awt.event.ActionEvent.` Также проверил, какие java-библиотеки вообще видит Eclipse, оказалось, что только OpenJDK. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
    public MyAction() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // что-то делаем...
    }
}
```

Comment: проверил, всё равно не хочет. Та же самая ошибка

Comment: убери @Override

Comment: о, а теперь собралось, спасибо большое. А не знаете, почему он ругался на @Override?

Comment: Да, потому что у тебя Эклипс настроен под джаву 1.5, а используются классы из 1.6 и в 1.5 не было аннотаций

Comment: спасибо, буду знать